# Problem to store information in a hashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java

I have a problem to store data in this hashmap, I'm programming in Java.

My system consists of some chats, in the hash map I have to insert chats as indexes and the list of users who are connected to a specific chat, my problem is the initialization of the hashmap, as I only have to enter the chats but the arraylists are empty because there is no user connected, only I cannot understand how to do this correctly.

This is a little sample of my code:

```
public class Master {
   private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> chatBox;

   public Master() {
      chatBox = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
   }

   public insert() {
      FileReader fr;
      BufferedReader br;
      try {
        fr = new FileReader("listChat.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while(true) {
            String topic = br.readLine();
            if(topic == null)
                break;
            chatBox.put(topic, null);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
```

Comment: So, what's the concrete problem? null is not an empty ArrayList. It's no ArrayList at all. An empty ArrayList is created using `new ArrayList<>()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to change the code that way by creating an empty ArrayList when you add a new element in the hashmap:

```
while(true) {
        String topic = br.readLine();
        if(topic == null)
            break;
        chatBox.put(topic, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
```

When you will have to update this topic with messages, you get the value for the key "topic" and add new elements in the ArrayList

Comment: Thanks was just that mistake, I was getting lost in a glass of water.